# Databricks Permissions Required to Create a Cluster

Tags: azure-databricks

Can someone let me know what permissions are required to allow a user to create a cluster.

[image]

Also, is it safe to assume that 'Can manage', has higher permissions that 'Can restart' or 'Can attach'?

Comment: accepted answer is incorrect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create new clusters user needs to have either:

- Have permission to use a [cluster policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/clusters/policies-best-practices). This is a recommended way of giving users the ability to create new clusters (DLT, Jobs as well) because you can enforce specific settings, like, auto-termination time, tagging, etc.
- Give user/group the "Unrestricted cluster creation" entitlement (via Admin Settings).  This method isn't recommended...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Azure Databricks, if you want to create a cluster, you need to have the "**Can Manage**" permission.
This permission basically lets you handle everything related to clusters, like making new ones and controlling existing ones.

Now, within this system, having the "**Can Manage**" permission means you have more power than those with just "**Can Restart**" or "**Can Attach**" permissions.
With "**Can Manage,**" you can do it all - start, stop, resize, and even terminate clusters.

On the other hand, if you only have "**Can Restart**," you can only restart a cluster but not do any of the other management tasks.
Similarly, "**Can Attach**" lets you join an existing cluster, but you can't do any management stuff with it.

So, having the "**Can Manage**" permission basically means you've got the highest level of control when it comes to handling clusters in Azure Databricks.

As per [Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/auth-authz/access-control/cluster-acl) Any user with Can Manage permission for a cluster can configure whether a user can attach to, restart, resize, and manage that cluster.

Comment: It's incorrect... `Can Manage` will give you ability to change settings of existing cluster